# Porquê os dados vindos do formulário só são exibidos após o reenvio do formulário?

Tags: php, html, formulário, post

Estou desenvolvendo um gerenciador de tarefas. Obviamente necessito de uma função de adicionar tarefas.

```
function loadInputForm () {
    global $title, $status,$description, $date;

    if($_POST){
        $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "titulo");
        $status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "status");
        $description = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "descricao");
        $date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "data");
    }

    if($title){
        $taskInput = "$title%$status%$description%$date\n";
        addTasks($taskInput);
    }
}
```

Com o código acima eu recebo as informações do formulário e as salvo em um string com o separador "%".

```
 function addTasks ($taskInput) {
    $fileOpen = fopen(PATH, 'a');
    fwrite($fileOpen, $taskInput);
    fclose($fileOpen);
}
```

Aqui eu abro um arquivo com uma função nativa do PHP e escrevo a string com os dados do formulário nesse arquivo com a função fwrite(). Para a interface eu simplesmente quebro o texto desse arquivo com funções de manipulação de strings e as exibo pro usuário.

O problema é que quando o usuário termina de preencher o form e aperta o botão de enviar os dados, a página é atualizada mas o conteúdo não é adicionado. Ele só aparece na interface após atualizar a página novamente. Daí surge outro problema, após essa segunda atualização da página, o formulário é reenviado, e os dados antes digitados pelo usuário são novamente escritos no arquivo, ocasionando uma repetição de conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o código que lê os dados está sendo executado **antes** da função `addTask()` ser executada.
Por isso ela só aparece após recarregar a página.
Tente executar ela antes, ou mover a função `addTask()` para outro endereço.

Por exemplo:

- Você está na página `exemplo.com/tasks`.
- O formulário faz o submit para `exemplo.com/tasks/add`.
- Após os dados serem salvos, o usuário é redirecionado de volta para `/task`.